# In React Js , about page's content is displaying double time?

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

The about page's content is displaying two times when I expect it to only display once. My app is written using React.js.

I tried to check the about page in app.js and check the props, but I haven't found the solution.

Here is my app.js page's code:

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import TextForm from './components/TextForm';
import About from './components/About';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Alert from './components/Alert';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('light'); // whether dark mode is enabled or not 
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

  const showAlert = (message, type)=>{
      setAlert({
        msg: message, 
        type: type
      })
      setTimeout(() => {
        setAlert(null);
      }, 1500);
  }
 
 
  const toggleMode = () => {
    if(mode === 'light'){
      setMode('dark');
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#0e4872';
      showAlert("Dark mode has been enabled", "success");
      document.title = 'TextUtils - Dark Mode';
      // setInterval(() => {
      //   document.title = 'TextUtils is Amazing app';
        
      // }, 2000);
      // setInterval(() => {
      //   document.title = 'Install TextUtils Now ';
      // }, 1500);
    }
    else{
      setMode('light');
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      showAlert("Light mode has been enabled", "success");
      document.title = 'TextUtils - Light Mode';
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Navbar title="TextUtils" mode = {mode} toggleMode={toggleMode} />
      <Alert alert = {alert} />
      <div className="container my-3">
        <Routes>
              <Route exact path ="/about" element ={<About/>}>
              </Route>
              <Route exact path ="/" element = {<TextForm showAlert ={showAlert} heading="Enter the text to analyze below" mode={mode}/>}>
              </Route>  
        </Routes>
        
       <About mode={mode} />
      </div>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
} 


export default App;
```

How can I make it only display the `about.js` page content once?

Comment: Because you render `<About />` two times

Comment: yes, thankyou for informing this to me. My issue is resolved now thankyou so much.

Answer (score 0):

React router does render the About component whenever you access /about in url. Thanks to that other `<About />` component in render function is not neccesary.

Comment: Thankyou for answering my question and error my error is now resolved. Thankyou so much.

Comment: No problem budy. Happy hacking!